# Probability Distribution of two discrete random variables via product of their characteristic functions

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$, $Y$ be two discrete random variables. If we want to find the probability mass function of $Z=X+Y$, can we can we consider multiplying the characteristic functions of $X$ and $Y$, and then take  the inverse fourier transform of the product of the characteristic functions to get the pmf of $Z$. I know we can do this with continuous random variables (this is a standard way to find the density of the sum of two gaussians), but can we do the same for discrete random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are independent; If they are not, you cannot use CF even for continuous random variables.

Comment: Thank you. Could you guide me to any documentation on the subject?